# Will this processor work fine with my integrated graphics chipset?

Tags: cpu, integrated-graphics, intel-graphics

Trying to upgrade my processor from a core 2 duo to a core 2 extreme quad core but can't seem to find anything that says if they're compatible and don't want to spend the money on a processor that doesn't work with the graphics card.

The graphics card is an Intel 4500MHD Integrated Graphics card if it helps.

Make: Gateway
Model: MD7818u
Socket: Socket P (I know this is the right socket at least)
Bios: Phoenix Technologies LTD Version 99.07

Comment: The processor and graphics cards are not components that are usually problematic. What you need to tell us is the make and model of the motherboard and the model numbers of the processor. On modern Intel processors the integrated graphics is usually on the same chip as the processor so by replacing the processor you are also changing the graphics too. We need more details on your system. Basically we need any and all system specifications you can get. A programming called Speccy might help.

Comment: Provided their socket power requirements, and therma limits are the same you should be fine, everything is on Intels website

Comment: Processor upgrades are limited by the socket and the Bios, if the bios does not have the microcode it needs for a specific processor, it will not work. So we need to know the make and model of the PC to attempt finding what processor upgrades can be sone for that specific model, bios and motherboard.

Comment: @Mokubai added a bit more information.

Comment: [Socket P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_P) is the name for two related ways of connecting a processor to a motherboard.  One way is a BGA (Ball Grid Array) package where the processor is directly soldered to the board and the other is PGA (Pin Grid Array) where the processor plugs into a socket on the motherboard.  If you have the BGA variant then the processor **cannot** be replaced, the other... maybe.  Given [this video](http://youtu.be/wUkdO82NIa4?t=15m6s) it looks like it might be the PGA and thus replaceable version.  I have no idea *if* it would work though.

Comment: @Mokubai the exact socket is PGA478MN. I referred to it as socket p because that was the way most of the places to find a new processor were calling it.